# How to read otp sent on Mobile number while login into Power BI.(Have to avoid multifactor authenticator)

Tags: python, selenium, powerbi

I have to log in to Power Bi(web and not Power Bi desktop). For that, I need an email id, password, and OTP (every time I get a new OTP once I logged into power Bi) on my mobile. I was trying to automate the Scenario using selenium + python, passed the user id and password, but I was not able to pass OTP as it was sent to my mobile).

Tried Twillo API but that did not work. Tried to save the browser's cookies, but that also didn't work.

Can you please suggest what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In order to bypass OTP thing, you have to save cookies in folder(any folder).

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ='C:\\Users\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe',\
options = opt)
driver.get("https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/landing/signin/? 
ru=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.powerbi.com%2F%3FnoSignUpCheck%3D1")
```

Reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zrx8FSEo9lk&t=453s&ab_channel=MukeshotwaniMukeshotwani